# How to get all CIDR's of a existing VPC and add them to security group as inbound rules using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an existing VPC which has 4 CIDR's and I need to retrieve those CIDR's and add them to a security as Inbound rules. Is there any way to do it in Terraform? I didn't find a way to do that Terraform

```
data "aws_vpc" "example_vpc" {
  id = "vpc-xxxxx" # Replace with the ID of your VPC
}

output "vpc_cidr_block" {
  value = "${data.aws_vpc.example_vpc.cidr_block}"
}
```

I have tried above snippet but the output value is giving only Primary CIDR.

Terraform Version: v0.14.5

Comment: By 4 CIDRs you mean subnets?

Comment: No, You can optionally associate multiple IPv4 CIDR blocks to the VPC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get both the default CIDR block and the **associated** ones you need to use the `cidr_block_associations` attribute of the `aws_vpc` data source:

```
data "aws_vpc" "example" {
  id = "vpc-0f67a3b2exxxxxx"
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "example" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  protocol          = "tcp"
  cidr_blocks       = data.aws_vpc.example.cidr_block_associations[*].cidr_block
  security_group_id = "sg-0e40fe769816xxxxx"
}
```

The `cidr_block_associations` attribute looks like this:

```
cidr_block_associations = [
  {
    association_id = "vpc-cidr-assoc-0b3673ed50fcxxxxx"
    cidr_block     = "172.31.0.0/16" # default CIDR
    state          = "associated"
  },
  {
    association_id = "vpc-cidr-assoc-050fdc9392e9xxxxx"
    cidr_block     = "172.32.0.0/20" # associated CIDR
    state          = "associated"
  },
]
```

As you can see, it's a list of objects with 3 attributes. To extract just the `cidr_block` values I used [Terraform splat expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat) in my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [subnet_ids](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/subnet_ids) data source  to get the subnets for the VPC, and then use those subnets further in aws_subnet data source as shown in the official documentation to get all the CIDRs in the VPC. Pasting the example below from terraform docs.

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "example" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
}

data "aws_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = data.aws_subnet_ids.example.ids
  id       = each.value
}

output "subnet_cidr_blocks" {
  value = [for s in data.aws_subnet.example : s.cidr_block]
}
```